# Duvida de execução javac no cmd

Tags: java, cmd

Olá, estou começando agora em Java e queria saber como compilar o .java em .class de uma maneira direta.
Sei executar o javac no cmd mas faço assim:

```
cd C:\Local\

javac HelloWorld.java
```

Mas eu gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de fazer isso em uma linha só.
Vou usar isso em um projeto que vai fazer isso automaticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd C:\Local\ && javac HelloWorld.java
```